# Bootstrapping across residuals for heteroscedastic data

Tags: bootstrap, error, heteroscedasticity, curve-fitting

I have a highly heteroscedastic 2d dataset (x,y) where both x and y cover about 3 orders of magnitude; therefore, although the % error is roughly constant and normally distributed across x, the absolute error is an order of magnitude or two greater at one end of the dataset than at the other. We could of course log-transform both x and y but this distorts the error structure. I'm fitting a curve to this using 1/x weighting and would like to estimate the confidence interval on my predictions and on the parameters from my fit, ideally using bootstrapping (my preferred approach).

The equation of the curve can be justified from the underlying physics so we are quite certain it is the correct equation to use; therefore, I think I'm justified in using bootstrapping across residuals rather than cases (as I understand it, bootstrapping across cases is preferred in cases where we are uncertain about the curve / structure of the model we want to use / hyperparameters we want to choose etc.) Here's my problem -- it seems absurd to bootstrap across residuals in this case because the residuals for datapoints from large x are 1-2 orders of magnitude greater than the residuals for datapoints from small x (because of the large range covered by the curve).

Is it justifiable to bootstrap across residuals but using residual as % of y-actual for the datapoints? It makes sense to me given that it is the % error which is normally distributed for all x, not the absolute error, but I'm not sure if this can be more rigorously justified or is even common practice. If that is not justifiable, what would be the most correct way to apply the bootstrapping approach to estimation of CI in this case?

Comment: Would it make sense to curve fit to the lowest sum of relative error squared, rather than the (standard) lowest sum of absolute error squared? I have had occasion to do this type of fitting in the past, and this sounds like a case where this technique might be useful.

Comment: thanks, that's an interesting approach I hadn't thought of. I might try that.